# app engine cron jobs not running in production

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

I just uploaded my application to app engine and everything seems to be working correctly except that the cron jobs are not running. I have a cron.yaml file in my root directory which is basically:

```
cron:
- description: do stuff
  url: /cron/dostuff
  schedule: every 1 minutes

- description: do other stuff
  url: /cron/dootherstuff
  schedule: every 1 days
```

This maps to the following portion of my app.yaml file:

```
- url: /cron
  script: main.py
  login: admin
```

Which maps to my application in main.py where it says:

```
# cron
('/cron/(.*)',handlers.CronHandler),
```

Which finally maps to the CronHandler program like so:

```
class CronHandler(BaseHandler):
    def get(self, mode=""):
        if mode == "dostuff":
            # stuff should happen here
```

I've uploaded the app to google and everything else seems to be working correctly. And when I hit the cron URLs directly (i.e., myapp.appspot.com/cron/dostuff) it works correctly. But the cron jobs don't run on their own, and when I go in to the dashboard and view the Cron Jobs page, I see this.

[image]

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The dot-star isn't required for other entries so I wouldn't think that would matter, but I just gave this a try anyway. No dice. I agree, I would expect it to at least show some cron jobs that are failing.

Comment: Other variations I've tried are to adjust the frequency in cron.yaml to "schedule: every minute" and "schedule: every day". That also did not work.

Comment: .* is required - but I presume you have a catchall rule that also directs to main.py. The upshot of this is that your cron handlers are not admin-only.

Answer (score 3):

Got it figured out. "days" on its own without a specified time is not a valid schedule. I needed to change that to "every 24 hours" or "every day 00:00". Would be great if the docs on cron.yaml were a little more clear about the options.